# Fnd $ \int\frac{e^{-2x-x^2}}{( x+1)^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Find $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{-2x-x^2}}{\left( x+1\right)^2}\hspace{1mm}dx$.

If I do Integration by parts, I end up with $\displaystyle\int e^{-2x-x^2}\hspace{1mm}dx$

Which I believe cannot be integrated

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2} < \infty$ (i.e. it's integrable). moreover $e^{-2x -x^2} = e^{-(x+1)^2} e$

Comment: Complete the square, change variable $x+1=y$ and you will arrive to something looking like $\int e^{-y^2} dy$ which leads to the $ \text{erf}(y)$

Answer (score 8):

Since
$$\int \frac{e^{-2x-x^2}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx = e\cdot\int \frac{e^{-(x+1)^2}}{(x+1)^2}$$
your question is equivalent to finding a primitive for $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$. Integration by parts gives:
$$\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2} = -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}-\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\operatorname{Erf}(x).$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $$\int \frac{e^{(-2x-x^2)}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx=\int e\cdot\frac{e^{(-1-2x-x^2)}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx=\int e\frac{e^{-(x+1)^2}}{(x+1)^2}\,d(x+1)$$
Substitute $y=x+1$ to get (using integration by parts) 
$$\int e\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y^2}\,dy=e\int \frac{e^{-y^2}}{y^2}\,dy=e\Big(-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y}+\int\frac{-2ye^{-y^2}}{y}\,dy\Big)=e\Big(-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y}-2\int e^{-y^2}\,dy\Big)=e\Big(-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y}-\sqrt{\pi}\cdot erf(y)\Big)$$
Substitute back $y=x+1$ to get the desired result.